# Application or script that can generate folder structure + make a copy of a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

For my work, each time we bring on a new client we need to create a new folder structure in google drive (the same structure for every account) and in one folder we generate a copy of a google sheet that we have. This is rather time consuming, so was hoping there was a way to easily duplicate a google drive folder structure and have it make a copy of the google sheet that we include in one of the folders.

The perfect result would be to easily copy/duplicate an exact folder structure (obviously renaming it for the client) and then have the folder have the copy of the google sheet in the correct folder already

Comment: What kind of a structure do you want and how to do figure out the names of the folders and files that make up the structure?

Comment: So it's a really simple structure -   Main Folder (Brand Name) - within that folder there are 2 more (Brand Name Live) + (Edited) -  Edited is left empty - within (Brand Name Live) there would be the google sheet template and a 1 folder (Images) - Within the Images folder there are 3 folders (Ecommerce) + (Lifestyles) + (Model)

Comment: I hope that makes sense, not sure how to type it out exactly -  This isn't difficult to do, but we are constantly adding them and it feels really repetitive - so was hoping there was a way to automate some of these processes

Comment: Is "BrandName" a variable?

Comment: In an ideal world that would be incredible - but I don't mind manually going in and editing the brand name - that would still be much faster :)  Each brand that we bring on gets one of these folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Creating a folder structure

```
function createClientAccountFolder(brandName) {
  //var brandName=brandName || 'BrandName';
  var Template1=DriveApp.getFileById('TemplateId');//You need to add the id of your template here
  var acctRoot=DriveApp.getFolderById('Accounts Root Folder Id');//you need to add the id of the root accounts folder here
  if(brandName) {
    var mainFldr=acctRoot.createFolder(Utilities.formatString('MainFolder-%s',brandName));
    var liveFldr=mainFldr.createFolder(Utilities.formatString('%s-Live',brandName));
    var editedFldr=mainFldr.createFolder(Utilities.formatString('%s-Edited',brandName));
    var imgsFldr=liveFldr.createFolder('Images');
    imgsFldr.createFolder('Ecommerce');
    imgsFldr.createFolder('LifeStyles');
    imgsFldr.createFolder('Model');
    Template1.makeCopy(liveFldr);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Brand Name Specified')
  }
}
```

> You could enhance this script with a dialog that allows you to select different folders and possibly even add additional root account folders and the same with templates.  But that is considerably more involved than what you have now.

Comment: Oh my god, you are incredible! So if I want the google sheet that goes in the "brand live" folder to be a specific template - can I copy a URL or something into this? Sorry if this is something that is obvious from looking at this - obviously this is a bit out of my comfort zone. Thank you again SO much for the help here!

Comment: All you need to do is put the template ID in the var Template1= declaration.

Comment: You also have to supply the folder ID

Comment: Thanks for your input I’ll add a little bit more explanation and answer